# Prevent WebView from running Javascript until it is visible

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm working on an Android application in which I pre-load a `URL` to a `WebView` (simply with `webview.loadUrl("www.google.com")`). Then, at some later point, I display the `WebView` by adding it to a visible view. I do this so that the `WebView` isn't fetching information when it's being shown. it already has the website downloaded.

The problem with this is, if I load up a website that contains JavaScript, the JavaScript runs immediately (in the background) when the `WebView` finishes loading instead of once the `WebView` is shown.

I would rather the `WebView` just download the website, then, once it is shown, begin running the scripts contained. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this yet but the docs say that you can disable JavaScript execution in a `WebView` using `WebSettings` [setJavaScriptEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29) method:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

You could toggle this flag when you are loading and displaying the `WebView`.